# How to handle DropZone.js file upload completed

Tags: javascript, image, dropzone.js

After my file is uploaded, I want to be able to move it out of the DropZone HTML element and into a LI item.

HTML Structur

```
<div class="dropzone"> FROM HERE.jpg </div>

<ul>
    <li>TO HERE.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(function() {



  // event listeners
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydrop", { url: "/images/upload/"});


  //NOT WORKING
  myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    file.previewElement.addEventListener("click", function() { 

  });  



  //feedback
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {


    init: function() 
    {
          this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
           //do stuff
          });          
          this.on("complete", function(file) {
           //do stuff
          });  
          this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
           //do stuff
          });
          this.on("uploadprogress", function(file) {
           //do stuff
          });          

    }

  };


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your complete function:

```
myDropzone.removeFile(file);
```